# Rolling average in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, statistics

I would like to do rolling average on data, x and y values.

e.g.

```rb
rolling_average([[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3]])
```

would give me

```
[[0, 2.0], [1, 2.5], [2, 3.0]]
```

I couldn't find anywhere how to do it

Answer (score 1):

I believe [rolling average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) (a.ka. *moving average*) is a misnomer here, but the desired calculation could be performed as follows.

```
def rolling_average(data)
  tot = 0
  sz = data.size
  data.reverse_each.with_object([]) do |(i,n),a|
     tot += n     
     a.unshift([i, tot.fdiv(sz-i)])
  end
end
```

```
rolling_average [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3]]
  #=> [[0, 2.0], [1, 2.5], [2, 3.0]]
```

```
data = 10.times.map { rand(10) }
  #=> [[0, 5], [1, 7], [2, 9], [3, 4], [4, 0],
  #    [5, 5], [6, 1], [7, 6], [8, 3], [9, 5]]
rolling_average data # to 3 decimal places
  #=>[[0, 4.5], [1, 4.444], [2, 4.125], [3, 3.428], [4, 3.333],
  #   [5, 4.0], [6, 3.75], [7, 4.666], [8, 4.0], [9, 5.0]]
```

Keeping a running total avoids the need to perform a complete summation for each element in `data`.

---

Though ever-so-slightly less efficient, it may be clear to write the following.

```
def rolling_average(data)
  tot = data.sum(&:last)
  sz = data.size
  data.map do |i,n|
     avg = tot.fdiv(sz-i)
     tot -= n     
     [i, avg]
  end
end
```

---

To compute a rolling average of size `avg_size` one could compute the following, where `data` is simply an array of values to be averaged.

```
def rolling_average(data, avg_size)
  raise ArgumentError if data.size < avg_size
  block = data.first(avg_size)
  tot = block.sum
  sz = data.size
  (avg_size..sz).map do |i|
    avg = tot.fdiv(avg_size)
    if i < sz
      x = data[i]
      tot += x - block.first
      (block << x).shift
    end
    avg
  end
end
```

```
data = [5, 7, 9, 4, 0, 5, 1, 6, 3, 5]

rolling_average(data, 3)
  #=> [7.0, 6.667, 4.333, 3.0, 2.0, 4.0, 3.333, 4.667]
```

The first element of the array returned by `rolling_average` equals `(5 + 7 + 9)/3.0 #=> 7.0`, the second equals `(7 + 9 + 4)/3.0 #=> 6.667`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```rb
def rolling_average(data, size = 10)
  data.map.with_index do |_, i|
    [
      data[i].first,
      data[i..(i + size)].map(&:last).then { |a| a.sum.to_f / a.size }
    ]
  end
end
```